# How to add id (instead of object) in ManyToManyField of Django model?

Tags: django

models.py :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Department(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to save employee ids (instead of employee object) in 'employee' ManyToManyField of 'Department' model. How to do that?

views.py:

```
dept = Department(name=name)
dept.save()
employee_ids = [1,2]
```

Comment: why do you wanna do that?

Comment: You can create an object like: `dept = Department.objects.create(name=name, employee_id=1)`

Comment: @NKSM I have edited the question. Please check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use method [**`add`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)):

> Adds the specified model objects to the related object set.

```
dept = Department.objects.create(name=name)
dept.employee.add(*[1, 2])
```

Or method [**`set`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set)):

> Replace the set of related objects

```
dept.employee.set([1, 2])
```

---

> Note that `add()`, `create()`, `remove()`, `clear()`, and `set()` all
> apply database changes immediately for all types of related fields. In
> other words, there is no need to call save() on either end of the
> relationship.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that you had to give `set()` a list of Employee instances, like this: `set([emp_obj_1, emp_obj_2])`. But it turns out that, for many-to-many fields, it is also valid to pass a list of primary key values `[1, 2]` as you are showing here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is unclear what exactly are you trying to do ?
If you want to create a relation between  `department` and `employee` on the database level django does that for you

on your current structure the relation and is like

```
id|department_id|user_id
--|-------------|-------
 1|     3       |  2
```

Comment: I have edited the question.Please check that.